# Fetching Book Title from Google Books API with ISBN

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, fetch-api, google-books

I'm very very new to Javascript and React-Native and am building just a very simple app that can scan the barcode of a book for the ISBN and then match it to the title of the book.

I think I've managed to get the ISBN number and am trying to fetch the book title from google-books API, but I keep getting the error "undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this.state.results.items[0].title)". Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong and what steps I can take to fix it? Thank you! Sorry if there are a ton of mistakes or my code is terrible. I'm really new to this and appreciate the help!

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state= {
      results: {
        kind: '',
        totalItems: 0,
        items: []
      }
    }
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
  }


  fetchData(isbn) {
    fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes? 
   q=isbn:${encodeURIComponent(isbn)}`)
    .then((response)=> response.json())
    .then((responseData)=> {
      this.setState({results: responseData})
    });

  }

  _handleBarCodeRead = ({ type, data }) => {
    var isbn = data;
    this.fetchData(isbn)
    var title = this.state.results.items[0].volumeInfo.title;
    alert(`ISBN: ${isbn}, Title: ${title}`)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeRead={this._handleBarCodeRead}
        style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, styles.container]}
      >
        <View style={styles.layerTop} />
        <View style={styles.layerCenter}>
          <View style={styles.layerLeft} />
          <View style={styles.focused} />
          <View style={styles.layerRight} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.layerBottom} />
      </BarCodeScanner>
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: So, I was missing the "isbn:" in my url, which was causing me to get incorrect book titles. I fixed that and now in the alert, I'm getting the correct book title matched with the ISBN. However, even though I'm getting the Alert, still have the same undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.results.items[0].title)

Comment: Sounds like the first item is missing a title. Have you tried checking the returned data from `fetch`?

Comment: What ISBN are you trying?

Comment: What do you see if you change `.then((responseData)=> {this.setState({results: responseData})});` to `.then((responseData)=> { console.log('responseData', responseData); this.setState({results: responseData})});`? You'd see this in your console somewhere. I'm concerned since you initially define your `results` state as an object, but you probably receive your `results` from the API call as an array.

Comment: So I made the change you suggested and in my console, I'm seeing a LONG JSON object with details about a lot of books, much more than just the one title I was hoping to get back

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to get the `title` attribute in the wrong location.

Try changing to `var title = this.state.results.items[0].volumeInfo.title;`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, yeah I just noticed that after you said it. Now my Alert is showing a title, but it's not the title of the book I'm scanning for some reason. The title it's showing is by the same author though

Comment: Also, even though my alert message is showing ISBN and a book title, I'm still getting the same undefined is not an object error message

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition.
The alert is happening before the `setState` is executed. One way to get around this is to use a `callback()`.

```js
  fetchData(isbn, callback) {
    fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:${encodeURIComponent(isbn)}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
            this.setState({ bookInfo: responseJson.items[0].volumeInfo.title});
            callback();
        })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

  alertInfo = () => {
      var title = this.state.bookInfo;
      alert(`Title: ${title} was scanned!`);
  }


  handleBarCodeScanned = ({ data }) => {
    var isbn = data;
    this.setState({ scanned: true });
    this.fetchData(isbn, this.alertInfo);
  };
```